# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Version' to 'System.Net.HttpVersion'

Tags: c#, .net, system.net

Consider the following code:

```
void Main()
{
    HttpVersion version;
    string s = "HTTP/1.1";
    version = s == "HTTP/1.1" ? HttpVersion.Version11 : HttpVersion.Version10;
}
```

This throws the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Version' to 'System.Net.HttpVersion'

even though `System.Version` is nowhere inferred and isn't even part of [`HttpVersion`'s inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpversion%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Explicit casts

```
void Main()
{
    HttpVersion version;
    string s = "HTTP/1.1";
    version = s == "HTTP/1.1" ? (HttpVersion) HttpVersion.Version11 : (HttpVersion) HttpVersion.Version10;
}
```

or explicit namespace naming

```
void Main()
{
    System.Net.HttpVersion version;
    string s = "HTTP/1.1";
    version = s == "HTTP/1.1" ? System.Net.HttpVersion.Version11 : System.Net.HttpVersion.Version10;
}
```

don't make a difference.

The question is simple: why is `System.Version` interfering with what should be an unrelated class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Version10`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpversion.version10%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Version11`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpversion.version11%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) static fields of [`HttpVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpversion%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) return [`System.Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects, not `HttpVersion` objects. So it's not technically unrelated.

Now as for WHY it does that, I have absolutely no idea. But you'll note that the places where it is used (such as [`HttpWebRequest.ProtocolVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.protocolversion%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) use `System.Version` as well. So that's what you want to be using.

To me, it kind of looks kind of like `HttpVersion` should have been a static class as it has no instance members that are not inherited from `Object`...

Comment: Huh, I read totally past that. It's a pretty awkward way of defining these values; I'm guessing it's because of the restrictions placed on enums in C# (no methods or inheritance on enums) and they worked around it like this. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

[`HttpVersion.Version11`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpversion.version11%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [`HttpVersion.Version10`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpversion.version10%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) both return a `Version` object, which you're trying to store in an `HttpVersion` variable.